# I am trying to write a GUI app for ChatGPT using com.theokanning.openai.service.OpenAIService

Tags: java, openai-api

I am currently getting tijavameouts.

I have the following code when setting up the OpenAIService.

```java
            service = new OpenAiService(apiKey, Duration.ZERO);
```

and the call to set up the request

```java
 // Process the user's message with OpenAI
        ChatCompletionRequest chatRequest = ChatCompletionRequest.builder( )
                                                                 .model( OPENAI_MODEL ) // see https://platform.openai.com/docs/models
                                                                  // if option enabled, send history
                                                                 .messages( !options.get( "disableSendingChatGPTHistory" ) ? returnHistoryAsList() : null )
                                                                 .maxTokens( 256 )
                                                                 .build( );

        ChatMessage response = service.createChatCompletion( chatRequest ).getChoices( )
                                                                          .get( 0 )
                                                                          .getMessage( );
```

This should be set uo to have zero timeout but I still get the following stack trace.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at io.reactivex.internal.util.ExceptionHelper.wrapOrThrow (ExceptionHelper.java:45)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BlockingMultiObserver.blockingGet (BlockingMultiObserver.java:90)
    at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet (Single.java:2002)
    at com.theokanning.openai.service.OpenAiService.execute (OpenAiService.java:321)
    at com.theokanning.openai.service.OpenAiService.createChatCompletion (OpenAiService.java:135)
    at com.jareid.openaiapp.api.APIHandler.askGPT_GetResponse (APIHandler.java:372)
    at com.jareid.openaiapp.ui.UserInterfaceScreen.lambda$new$4 (UserInterfaceScreen.java:121)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed (AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed (AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed (DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed (DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased (BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent (Component.java:6635)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent (JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent (Component.java:6400)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent (Container.java:2263)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl (Component.java:5011)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl (Container.java:2321)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent (Component.java:4843)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent (Container.java:4918)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent (Container.java:4547)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent (Container.java:4488)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl (Container.java:2307)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl (Window.java:2772)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent (Component.java:4843)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl (EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run (EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run (EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege (ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege (ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run (EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run (EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege (ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent (EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters (EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter (EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy (EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents (EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents (EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run (EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong and why it is still timing out

Answer (score 0):

Increase the wait time for your response timeout duration:

```
service = new OpenAiService(apiKey, Duration.ofSeconds(10000));
```

SocketTimeoutException happened because you set your wait time for a response to zero 'Duration.ZERO'.